# Complete or Large List of Mathematical Objects?

Tags: reference-request

I am working on a language translation project and would like to come up with translations for as many mathematical objects as I can easily do. Searching "list of mathematical objects" doesn't yield much, such as [this extremely short list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_object#List_of_mathematical_objects_by_branch). They don't even list "algebra" as a type of object, amongst many other things like complex numbers, derivatives, etc.. Instead, I am manually going through each page on the [list of mathematical topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematics_topics) on Wikipedia and finding the math objects through that. But I wanted to ask if there is anything more robust and already collected out there.

One example that provides more objects is the [list of named matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_matrices) page.

Does there exist a comprehensive or at least large list of mathematical objects somewhere on the web? Either just general types (along the lines of the first Wikipedia link), or general *and specific* types like the list of named matrices page? Not only would it help for my translation project, it would also help for understanding the full scope of mathematics and getting a broad overview of what is out there in terms of objects which are reasoned about.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187001/combinatorial-databases

Comment: @JMP can you please be more specific?

Comment: About what? It's a link to links to DB's of mathematical objects.

Comment: Many of the links are broken and/or I don't know where exactly to look in the link, so it would help to be more specific, and describe what I should be finding at each link.

Comment: 'Does there exist a comprehensive or at least large list of mathematical objects somewhere on the web?'

Comment: You can edit the short list on wikipedia.